when I upload image to firebase storage I want to append image urls to inside of array which located in manager class. but it returns empty array
class ServiceManager : ObservableObject {

func uploadImage(images: [UIImage], customerId: String, imageUrls: [String]) async throws {
    
    
    guard images.count <= 3 && !images.isEmpty else { return }
  
    images.enumerated().forEach { (index,image) in
    
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2) else { return }
        
        let path = "\(customerId)images/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"

        
        let storageRef = storage.reference().child(path)
       
        
        let _ = storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        
            
            if error == nil && metadata != nil {
                
             self.imageUrls.append(path) //  problem here
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }

This is the func in manager class which uploads photo. after make sure error == nil I want to append those paths to array. I tried as inout parameter but when async functions it s not a good idea I think. How to handle this?

Shouldn't the method be func uploadImage(images: [UIImage], customerId: String) async throws -> [String]? Why put the imageURLs in the parameters? Also, the calls you're doing are asynchronous, but don't use async/await, so self.imageUrls.append(path) will be called AFTER the method return. You might want to use withCheckedContinuation (or the throwing one), or if Firebase has it, use the async/await equivalent method.
